# Memory leak in const member constructor with tag dispatching

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, constructor, c++14

I have a class `Bar`, which has a member of the type `Foo`. The class `Foo` should be only constructed in certain fixed and constant states, which are discriminated base on a `Tag`. Since I do not want `Foo` to be constructed in any other state, I made its constructor private and implemented a factory `FooFactory`.

In the initializer list of `Bar`'s constructor, I call the function `make_Foo`, which returns the correct instance of `Foo` based on the `Tag`.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum class Tag
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

class Foo
{
public:
    friend class FooFactory;
    const Tag tag;
    const std::string string;
private:
    Foo(Tag tag, std::string string): 
    tag {tag}, string {string}
    {};
};

class FooFactory
{
public:
    static Foo A()
    {
        return Foo(Tag::A, {"This is string A"});
    }

    static Foo B()
    {
        return Foo(Tag::B, {"This is string A"});
    }
};

Foo make_Foo(Tag tag)
{
    switch(tag)
    {
        case Tag::A: return FooFactory::A();
        case Tag::B: return FooFactory::B();
        default: throw std::runtime_error("Called with invalid Tag.");
    }
}

class Bar
{
public:
    std::string another_string;
    const Foo foo;

    Bar(Tag tag, std::string another_string): 
    another_string {another_string}, foo {make_Foo(tag)}
    {};
};

int main()
{
    Tag tag = Tag::C;
    Bar bar(tag, "This is a string");
    std::cout << "bar constructed" << std::endl;
}
```

I want an exception to be thrown when `Foo` is constructed with `Tag::C`, which is not implemented. The above code throws this exception, but Valgrind Memcheck says that there is a memory leak in this case.

Upon further investigation, I see that even though `bar.foo` is not created by the factory when `Tag::C` is passed, `bar.foo` is still initialized with an unknown `Tag` and an empty `std::string`. Is this the memory that is leaked in this case? How can I avoid this from happening when the exception is thrown?

ps. In reality `Foo` is a non-type template class, and for `Tag::C`, another template parameter is used. That is why I need the tag dispatching.

Comment: Just a hunch: Do you still get the memory leak, if you switch order of declaration, of `another_string`, and `foo` in `Bar`?

Comment: Do you still get the leak if you catch the exception properly? Bar(...) : try another_string {another_string}, foo {make_Foo(tag)} { /* ctor code*/} catch { *catch code*}

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: Yes, I also get the leak when I switch the order.

Comment: @Otto V. It does, or at least if I just rethrow it after it has been caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a "memory leak" because the program terminates prematurely. In order to execute all destructors and deallocate memory, you must not allow an exception to escape the `main` function (or otherwise call `std::abort` or otherwise cause a terminal signal to be raised).

Objects with static duration are destroyed after main returns and this cleanup of static objects doesn't happen if the process is terminated. Such static objects may have allocated dynamic memory that can leak if the static objects are not destroyed. Even if you don't, the standard library may use objects with static storage. For example, the `std::cout` object.

Comment: I thought that the exception handling mechanism should clean up the objects (as long as not created with `new` or `delete`) when they go out of scope? Should I then catch the exception in `main`, and let `main` return with some exit code, to indicate that something went wrong?

Comment: @JorenV objects with static duration are destroyed after main returns and this cleanup of static objects doesn't happen if the process is terminated. Such static objects may have allocate dynamic memory that can leak if the static objects are not destroyed. Even if you don't, the standard library may use objects with static storage. For example, the `std::cout` object.

Comment: `Should I then catch the exception in main, and let main return with some exit code, to indicate that something went wrong? ` Why not simply let the memory "leak"? Your program is terminated, so why would you care about memory?

Comment: Well, I do not know what is the proper way of dealing with this. Maybe I should indeed not care. I started worrying about this because I run my program on a cluster, which generates core dump files when not all the memory is cleaned up properly.

Comment: I did not think about the static object. That will indeed probably be the problem!

Comment: @JorenV are you sure that core dump is generated because of a memory leak? Usually SIGQUIT,SIGILL,SIGABRT,SIGFPE,SIGSEGV cause a core dump, of which SIGABRT is what you get when the program is terminated by an unhandled exception. Wouldn't a core dump be useful in this case? To help find out why the process was terminated.

Comment: Ah, that could be the case. In either case, not handling the excpetion in `main` is apparently the root cause of the core dump. In this specific case, I do not need the information from the core dump, just the exit code from the program is enough.